# access multiple urls and read content of the site using python

Tags: python, url

I have a text file links.txt. It had 100 urls with http and https. I want to open that urls and search for some specific strings in every site.
This is what I have written so far. I am getting SSL error:

```
with open ("links.txt") as txt_file:        
    for line in txt_file.readlines():               
          print line
          html =urllib2.urlopen(line).read()

          print html
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `urlopen`:

> The optional cafile and capath parameters specify a set of trusted CA certificates for HTTPS requests. cafile should point to a single file containing a bundle of CA certificates, whereas capath should point to a directory of hashed certificate files. More information can be found in ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations().